# ADSTS50011: The reply address does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: More details: not specified

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, single-sign-on

So I am trying to set up AD for a friend which was supposed to be a 'simple thing'. It is driving me mad.

I set up a template MVC site with AD to connect to a single organisation. I did notice that at this point, as expected, the reply address is automatically set to localhost in the web.config on my local machine. I log-in using a valid account they have set me up and **all works ok** *(at this point I am thinking amazingly easy this)* until I deploy it onto the test server *(loses multiple strands of hair and hours of playing with configs)*.

I changed the key="ida:postRedirectUri" to the url of the site:

```
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://localhost:44348/" />
to
<add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://theurl.org/sso/home" />
```

just to explain what the /sso/home is... the app is a virtual app within the companies site (its classic asp website). I don't believe this is the issue.

now the error message I get is:

> Request Id: 18xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Correlation Id: 32xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
>
> Timestamp: 2018-02-28T21:55:55Z
>
> Message: AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://theurl.org/sso/home'
>   does not match the reply addresses configured for the application:
>   '23xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'. More details: not specified

Reading around people seem to say "add the reply urls in the portal of the app setup in Azure". I have not set up any app in azure and I don't have any access to their portal.

EDIT: I have managed to get the azure portal updated but no luck.. are these settings correct. Noticed the APP ID URI is a different URL to the site which makes sense for the company, not sure if this has an impact?

[AD Azure Portal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL6iW.png)

Comment: Your web.config has a `ClientId` key and starts with "23...". Now you'll have to go to the Azure AD portal (https://aad.portal.azure.com), login as tenant admin, and add the reply address under the app registration (match the ClientId to locate the right app).

Comment: You should have an extra key, usually called `ida:RedirectUri` and that's what you should amend to point to your public URL. The `PostLogoutRedirectUri`, while triggering the same error, isn't doing you much good really, hence the name. Someone set up this app in Azure AD, otherwise you wouldn't be able to login at all, local or not.

Comment: Yes your right I put the wrong key in the description... I will see if I can get that updated and come back .. thanks for your help

Comment: Well, If you need to resolved this issue, you need to know or configure the reply URL in the application from Azure AD. Try to contact the admin of that AAD.

Comment: I have edited the original and added an image of the portal settings. No luck so far.

Comment: I am really stuck now! I read another post indicating that removing the localhost element from the reply uri's would work but to no avail.